# How would I create a custom progress bar with changing text?

Tags: c#

I am editing this question because after reading it over I feel like it did not make any sense. My first attempt was to use Thread.Sleep which I now realize makes no sense for this.

Comment: Why not just use an actual [ProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: I don't like a way the Normal one looks I made mine look different

Comment: What's with the `Thread.Sleep` calls?  Are you trying to use a `Sleep` as a placeholder for something?  The `Sleep` calls are a problem the way you've done it.

Comment: Your changes would normally take effect when you return from `timer1_Tick`.  By sleeping inside that function, you are preventing the main thread from updating your form.  Depending on how you **actually** want to trigger updates, that will dictate what the solution will be.  Either just use a timer, or respond to whatever asynchronous event should be triggering each step.

Comment: Are you **actually** going to _download data_, and _check data_?  Or are you just making a toy that pretends to do those things by sleeping?  It makes a huge difference.  If you aren't actually doing to do the real actions, then you'll need a timer or a Task.delay to control the pace of it.  If you are actually going to wait for a download to complete, then we can demonstrate how to set it up so that progress updates when the download completes.  Hint:  That will be a separate event.

Comment: Yea sorry I should have been more clear. I was planing to use this as a auto updater for my program. Your solution still worked great for what I needed thank you. Sorry for randomly commenting here again I was just looking at some of my questions and realized my question was unclear and made no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/await to accomplish your goal.

By making the event handler asynchronous, you keep the main thread responsive.  It means that you should be using an awaitable (asynchronous) substitute for `Thread.Sleep` (which is the thing that caused your original solution not to work as you hoped).  In this case you can use `Task.Delay` instead of sleeping.

```
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1130);
    panel3.Width += 77;
    await Task.Delay(1130);
    panel3.Width += 77;
    label2.Text = "Starting...";
    await Task.Delay(1130);
    panel3.Width += 77;
    label2.Text = "Downloading data...";
    await Task.Delay(1356);
    panel3.Width += 77;
    label2.Text = "Checking data...";
    await Task.Delay(1356);
    panel3.Width += 79;
    label2.Text = "Ready to launch!";
    await Task.Delay(1356);
}
```

Comment: The bar now reaches 387 almost instantly and the text changes extreamly quickly any ideas

Comment: what is the rate of your timer?  (Hint: This probably doesn't need a timer.  You can trigger it once.)

Comment: My timer rate is 4 intervals

Comment: `4` is 4 milliseconds.  You likely don't want to trigger this action every 4 milliseconds.

Comment: How would I do it with out a timer

Comment: What starts this pseudo-progress thing running?  A button click?  A form Load?  Start it from there.  Quick tip:  you need to start thinking in terms of _event driven programming_.  Everything you do should be in response to some kind of event.

Comment: Thank you so much I got to caught up trying to use the timer this makes way more sense

Answer (score -2):

You can invoke the method application.doevents();

Application. DoEvents() can be used to process the messages waiting in the queue on the UI thread when performing a long-running task in the UI thread. This has the benefit of making the UI seem more responsive and not "locked up" while a long task is running

It have base in Microsoft post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.doevents?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I agree with this solution, and I've seen it done before.. although I still want to go on the record as saying that intensive tasks shouldn't be done on the UI thread anyway, Application.DoEvents is a dirty "fix", and that the original approach by OP hurts my soul.

Comment: How would I use the Application.DoEvents()

Comment: Here an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.doevents?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @iawindowss,  **don't** use `Application.DoEvents`.  Tell us what happens in your app that you want to have cause the progress to be updated.  Time?  Some IO being completed?  What?  Then update the UI in response to *that* thing.